# Wix Toolset 3.11.2 - The localisation identifier 'xx' has been duplicated in multiple locations. Please resolve the conflict

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

Its my first project with Wix Toolset and Visual Stdio - im not counting simple turtorial with "Hello World" kind of application.

In my current project i do have only one localisation file, named common.wxl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WixLocalization Culture="en-us" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/localization">

  <String Id="Company">TestCompany</String>

  <String Id="ProductNameFolder">TestApp/[Buildversion]</String>

  <String Id="ProductName_x86">TestApp</String>
  <String Id="ProductName_x64">TestApp</String>

  <String Id="Description">Test Description​</String>
  <String Id="Comments">Designed by TestCompany</String>
  <String Id="Keywords">application, installer</String>

  <String Id="DowngradeErrorMessage">A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed.</String>

  <String Id="Language">1033</String>
</WixLocalization>
```

And that's it, there is nothing more inside the file. Also there's no any other localisation file. Still, when I am trying to build te WIX project I'm getting 9 errors about duplicated identifiers:

The localisation identifier 'xx' has been duplicated in multiple locations. Please resolve the conflict.

One error for each of ID's in my **`common.wxl`**. But i dont have any other localisation file, so how these identifiers could be duplicated ?

I'm trying to solve that for hours already... does anyone have any idea ?

I'm using WiX Toolset 3.11.2, and WiX Toolset Visual Studio 2019 Extension.

Comment: Do you have any extra files with *.wxl file extension in your project? Try to download the sample below and test from there by injecting one string at a time.

Comment: Hello ! I do have only one xml file. To be clear i just renamed it to English.xml. And i have been still getting errors about duplicated IDs. I discovered also something very weird - check please my comment under Stein Asmul answer.

Answer (score 1):

***WiX Localization***: Please try this WiX localization sample: https://github.com/glytzhkof/WiXLocalizationSample

***Pragmatic Advice***: If this sample project works for you, consider creating a new WiX project and migrating one construct at a time over whilst continually checking the build as you go. There could be unnecessary files included that cause such duplication errors. Perhaps also try to change the **`String Id`** field - for example from **`Description`** to **`MyDescription`**. Just to test.

---

You refer to an identifier in the localization file using the **`"!(loc.StringID)"`** format. This will expand these placeholder values with the actual string when the MSIs are getting built. Here is a compressed sample:

In your **`Project.wxs`** file:

```
<Product Id="*" Name="WixLocalizationSample" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0"
         Manufacturer="!(loc.Company)" UpgradeCode="PUT-GUID-HERE"   >

  <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine"
           Comments="!(loc.Comments)" Keywords="!(loc.Keywords)"
           Description="!(loc.Description)" />
```

In your localization file (**`English.wxl`**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WixLocalization Culture="en-us" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/localization">
  
  <String Id="Description">This is a long test description.</String>  
  <String Id="Comments">Designed by TestCompany</String>
  <String Id="Keywords">application, installer</String>
  <String Id="Company">TestCompany</String>

</WixLocalization>
```

Use **`CDATA`** if needed to escape XML delimiters.

Comment: thank You for your comment. I have checked localization example, my code does look the same. Problem here is in my opinion with localisation file, but i cant find what is exactly wrong. As i mentioned i do have only one file - i renamed it now to English.wxl, to be clear. Actually i did some test - i changed "Build action" of my xml file from "embeddedResource" to "none". And... errors are gone ! Even if theres no any "compiled" or "embedded" xml in project now, WIX dont complain about missing !(loc.xx) data. Is that possible that i do have some other, hidden xml file in project ?

Comment: Can you compile the project I link to above? Try that. You could have included too many references in your project (project references) or copied some of WiX's built-in localization files to your project folder? Do you have your project on github.com? I am sure it is a trifle.

Comment: yes, i can compile the example project.Also Your quess is right Stein, i copied parts of code from other project, and that was most likely the reason. Specially messing up in config in "Unloaded" project can have bad results. Im a good example of that. I ended up with just deleting problematic WIX project, creating new one, and configuring it carefuly step by step. So far localisation (the same file as before) works perfectly. No any Duplicated ID's messages ! Thank You for your help !

Comment: OK, great. My advice would be to get yourself checked into source control or make yourself a zip of the working version. Do as an old hardware guy I knew did: mark the zip backup with W for "working" (those were the cards that passed the smoke test: plug it in and watch for smoke). Have fun :-). I have adapted the answer above with a top section recommending a new project and migrating constructs.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing some migration from one repo to another with some improvements to the legacy installer and I had the same issue. The localization file was in a Wix library project that was referenced by the installer project. The error was because the Wix library project folder was in the same directory where the installer project file was.

This structure was generating the error:

```
solution/
├─ solution.sln
├─ installer.wixproj
├─ lib/
|  ├─ localization.wxl
```

Once I've changed the structure like below, it didn't complain:

```
solution/
    ├─ solution.sln
    ├─ installer.wixproj
lib/
    ├─ localization.wxl
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a WiX v3.11 project which I moved to v4 recently.

The original .wxl file had *EmbeddedResource* as its Visual Studio > Properties > Build Action.

After changing it to *Content* and rebuilding the project, I was able to solve the issue.